# In C how can I access/iterate through file descriptors that are added dynamically to an fd_set?

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to implement a server / multi client program in Linux with C using select() and fd_sets. I am trying to broadcast messages sent from one connected client to all other connected clients but I don't know how to access the sockets for other clients in the fd_set once they are added dynamically. I am trying to replicate an implementation of this I found in C++ but the fd_set in C doesn't have the properties as C++. This is the code I'm trying to replicate:

```
for(int i = 0; i < master.fd_count; i++)
{
    SOCKET outSock = master.fd_array[i];
    if(outSock != listening && outSock != sock)
    {
        send(outSock, buffer, 250);
    }
}
```

where `master` is the fd_set, `listening` is the original socket listening for new clients and `sock` is the socket the message about to be broadcast came from.

Can any one help me learn how to access the fd_set socket elements to be able to do `!=` comparisons on them like in the example. Or alternatively, point me to another method to implement the multi client setup where I can broadcast a message back to all connected clients. I initially tried using multi processes with  `fork()` pipes but I could not find enough information on how to implement that properly.

Comment: Usually you should keep track of the elements you added to the set in say a separate array and then iterate over that. You can check if an fd is in a set using `FD_ISSET`

Comment: Don't use `select`. Use `poll`. It's easier to use anyway, and the former has fundamental interface flaws that make it impossible to use high fd numbers without undefined behavior and hacks.

Answer (score 1):

In C, you use the macro `FD_ISSET` to find out whether a given bit is set or not. See the [manual page for `select`(2)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man2/select.2.html) for details.

The basic idea is that first you zero the set with `FD_ZERO`, then you set some bits with `FD_SET`, then you call `select()` (or `pselect()`, according to taste). When `select()` returns you iterate over the set and use `FD_ISSET` to find out whether you can do a non-blocking I/O operation on the specified descriptor.

There are many examples on the net; for example, [an example from IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzab6/xnonblock.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Keep your *own* list of connected "users", like a linked list of structures containing what is needed for each user (like username and other data) *and* the socket descriptor.

Then if you need to send a message to all users just iterate over this list. Since the structures contain all information about the user, it's easy to skip one or more users when iterating, for example to not send to the user from which the message originated.

---

Simple example

```
struct user
{
    char  *name;    // Name of the user
    SOCKET socket;  // Socket descriptor for communication
    // Other data needed for the user...
    struct user *next;  // For linking into a list
};

// The list of all users
struct user *users = NULL;

// Broadcast a message to *all* connected users
void broadcast(const char *message)
{
    for (struct user *u = users; u != NULL; u = u->next)
    {
        send(u->socket, message, strlen(message), 0);
    }
}

// Broadcast to all except a specific user
void broadcast_except_name(const char *message, const char *name)
{
    for (struct user *u = users; u != NULL; u = u->next)
    {
        if (strcmp(u->name, name) != 0)
        {
            send(u->socket, message, strlen(message), 0);
        }
    }
}

// Broadcast to all except a specific socket
void broadcast_except_socket(const char *message, SOCKET socket)
{
    for (struct user *u = users; u != NULL; u = u->next)
    {
        if (u->socket != socket)
        {
            send(u->socket, message, strlen(message), 0);
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>[Functions for creating or otherwise operating on the list omitted]</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Get in the habit of reading manpages. The one for [select(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/select) lists the macros provided for `fd_set`:

```
   void FD_CLR(int fd, fd_set *set);
   int  FD_ISSET(int fd, fd_set *set);
   void FD_SET(int fd, fd_set *set);
   void FD_ZERO(fd_set *set);
```

You can use `FD_SET` and `FD_ISSET` macros to set or test the bits in `fd_set` that correspond to your filedescriptors.